# How can I get rid of / with a html_entity_decode?

Tags: php, html

my question is pretty simple. How can I get rid of / (slashes) before ' and " when I echo out a $_POST['input']
This is a simple test that I did :

```
$var = htmlentities($_POST['messageC'], ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1');
    echo html_entity_decode($var, ENT_NOQUOTES);
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name="messageC"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="testsubmit">
</form>
```

With html_entity_decode, I thought that It could get rid of / but nothing seems to change with that function. The reason is that I am sending a mail with mail() but everytime I see all that slashes man..it's getting so annoying.

Comment: nothing appears where? The `<textarea>` *is* empty by your definition, it's not intended to display *anything*.

Comment: *"... I have a htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'). Is this the problem?..."* Why not try it and see?

Comment: Since your `Input` class is a magic black box for us we don't know anything about, there's no answer here.

Comment: I am sorry guys. My explanation was terrible. I edited my question now

Comment: What does `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc())` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean backslashes (`\`) and that your server has Magic Quotes enabled.

Either upgrade to a version of PHP that doesn't have Magic Quotes (5.4 or newer), or disable them.

For more info, see the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)